# AWS Redshift adding nodes and changing from Single-node to Multi-nodes to increase the disk size

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

As I am new to Redshift, I have the following questions.

When adding new node to increase the disk space which "distribution style" that i need to
choose?

As my purposes is increasing the disk space do i need to consider "distribution style" or any changes in already written    queries(queries works in single node without any issues)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Distribution becomes important as more and more nodes exist.

Each node will have at least 2 slices, depending how your data is distributed across these slices your performance may be affected when performing queries.

You can distribute in the following ways:

- `EVEN` - Datasets are distributed evenly between slices, whilst this will distribute the storage evenly across all nodes if you must perform joins to this data from other slices you might find a performance hit. It will benefit greatly from denormalized data with no joins as it will gain the CPU across each node to perform computation.
- `KEYS` - Datasets are distributed to slices based on their relationships with other data, this will really benefit when using joins in your tables but be aware that data can be distributed across slices unevenly.
- `ALL` - Every slice gets the entire dataset, use this option for small datasets (tables less than 10GB), or those with data that changes infrequently.
- `AUTO` - Redshift takes care of the distribution style and attempts to select the correct for the dataset, you have no control over the decisions it is making.

You should have a think about how you will use the data before making the decision as it will affect both the storage and performance output you get.

Comment: No problem, hope you found it useful :)